# Having Problem fetching rows from mysql table between two date columns

Tags: mysql

I am having the table and i want to fetch rows based on 'rb_rm_id' column between the 2 dates 'rb_chkin' and 'chkout'. But, It gives me 0 result even if the values are present. Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

I have Tried the Following Mysql Query but, failed:

```
SELECT * 
FROM room_booking 
WHERE `rb_rm_id` = 2 AND 
(`rb_chkin` >= '2019-08-05' AND `rb_chkin` <= '2019-08-06') AND 
(`rb_chkout` >= '2019-08-05' AND `rb_chkout` <= '2019-08-06');
```

The Table image is here [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7TDh.jpg "Table"

Comment: Can you add sample data as text to the question please.

Comment: I have provided the table image in the link

Comment: Which I cannot access...or use.

Comment: Is it Fine? [img]https://i.imgur.com/eQZ1I0C.png[/img]

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific - its a site rule that I cannot accept cookies - so I cannot access the image. Perhaps someone else will com along who can.

Comment: sorry for your troubles. Is this link helping? https://ibb.co/jWMsQLN

Comment: Which record do you expect? there is no record with checkin date 2019-08-05 or 2019-08-06

Comment: Why aren't you using the SQL `BETWEEN "2019-08-01" AND "2019-08-04"` clause to make your SQL easier to read and make MySQL know what you're trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

Your query says:

> Give me any rows where `rb_chkin` and `rb_chkout` both are between 2019-08-05 and  2019-08-06 and the `rb_rm_id` is 2.

There is no such row in your table.

What you probably want is to detect whether a room is booked during the given date range. For a room to be, at least partially, occupied there can three case:

1. The check-in date falls within the date range.
2. The check-out date falls within the date range.
3. The check-in date is before the date range, and the check-out is after the date range.

If either one of these three conditions is met the room has a booking during the given date range. The equivalent query would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM room_booking 
WHERE `rb_rm_id` = 2 AND 
      (`rb_chkin` BETWEEN '2019-08-05' AND '2019-08-06') OR
      (`rb_chkout` BETWEEN '2019-08-05' AND '2019-08-06') OR
      (`rb_chkin` < '2019-08-05' AND `rb_chkout` > '2019-08-06');
```

So this returns all rows that have a booking for the given room in the given date range.

Please consider using better column names, which would make your code actually readable. Something like: `rb_room_id`, `rb_customer_id`, `rb_check_in_date`, `rb_check_out_date`. I really don't understand this need for obfuscation.

Comment: Your answer is right for this case. But, for the case if 'rb_chkin' = 2019-08-01 and 'rb_chkout' = 2019-08-08, its shows no result measn vacant room where the room is book between 3rd to 7th. So, should get this result.

Comment: @D.Chatterjee Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Perhaps you forgot about the `rb_rm_id = 2`?

Comment: I meant what is rb_rm_id = 2,  'rb_chkin' = 2019-08-01 and 'rb_chkout' = 2019-08-08,

Comment: Ah, I think I get it... you're changing the query dates, not the dates in the database... and you get partial overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear and also your mysql table doesn't contains any value in that range. There is no check in value in your given range.

try this one

```
SELECT * 
FROM room_booking 
WHERE `rb_rm_id` = 2 AND 
(`rb_chkin` <= '2019-08-05' AND `rb_chkout` >= '2019-08-06');
```